# Filtering permutations to avoid running out of memory

Tags: r, bigdata, combinatorics

The context of this problem is asset allocation. If I have N assets, and can allocate them in 5% chunks, what are the permutations that exist such that the sum of the allocation is exactly equal to 100%.

For example if I had 2 assets there would be 21 (created using my function "fMakeAllocationsWeb(2)" code at the bottom of this post:

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    0  100
 [2,]    5   95
 [3,]   10   90
 [4,]   15   85
 [5,]   20   80
 [6,]   25   75
 [7,]   30   70
 [8,]   35   65
 [9,]   40   60
[10,]   45   55
[11,]   50   50
[12,]   55   45
[13,]   60   40
[14,]   65   35
[15,]   70   30
[16,]   75   25
[17,]   80   20
[18,]   85   15
[19,]   90   10
[20,]   95    5
[21,]  100    0
```

The problem of course come when the number of assets increases, even modestly. This is understandable as with repetition the number of permutations is n^(n) and I'm not able to allocate the intermediate step of creating all permutations to memory. For example with 20 assets the number of permutations is 5.84258701838598E+27!!

I would like to be able to filter these on the fly (sum==100) so as to not run into the memory allocation issue. Digging into the code beneath gtools::permutations it seems to be vectorised and intervening there to filter seems impossible.

Would gratefully welcome any thoughts - ideally would prefer to stick with R code and packages.

Many thanks

Russ

```
installifMissing <- function(sPackageName) {
  if (!sPackageName %in% installed.packages()) install.packages(sPackageName)
}


fMakeAllocationsWeb<-function(iNumAssets=10,iIncrement=5){
installifMissing("gtools")
require(gtools)

iAlloc<-seq(0,100,by=iIncrement) #'the allocation increments eg 0,5,10...,95,100
#'generate permutations
permut<-permutations(n=length(iAlloc),r=iNumAssets,v=iAlloc,repeats.allowed=TRUE)
#'filter permuatations for those which sum to exactly 100'
permutSum<-apply(permut,MARGIN=1,FUN=sum)
permut100<-permut[which(permutSum==100),]
return(permut100)
}
```

Comment: First thing to do: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  Rather obviously, you can't do anything useful with all possible combinations (permutations don't matter).  That is: what do you expect to do with these potential asset allocations?  E.g., are there "illegal" sets which you want to block out?  It's trivial to "remove" non-100% combos by randomly adding assets until you either hit 100% or force the last remaining option to a value which makes the current set equal 100%.

Comment: ok, fair point. The problem that I'm trying to solve is to plot a cloud of the expected return vs risk of each portfolio. Partly a graphical demonstration for management ("this is our current portfolio relative to all "possible" portfolios) and partly to numerically define the efficient frontier. I work for an insurer so the "risk" axis isn't volatility so an analytical solution isn't going to be possible.  I see what you are getting at with a randomised solution - I have something similar already but was't convinced it was covering the full set of "possible" portfolios.

Comment: Well, your "cloud" will have as many dimensions as there are assets, so basically impossible to visualize or display.  If you can group the assets by risk class (something that Vanguard and other mutual fund companies do for their clients), you can dramatically reduce the function space you need to explore.  That is, if there are 20 assets all of whose risk is `x` then it doesn't really matter which ones you select, just what their summed total % is.

Comment: Lots to think about, many thanks Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the `partitions` package, you have the `restrictedparts` function that will enumerate all the ways you can add *n* numbers together to get a sum *S*.  In your case, you want to restrict the summands to be multiples of 5, and the restriction is to add up to *S=100*.  Instead, divide your summands by 5 and have the total add up to 20.  If you want 2 assets, then the code `restrictedparts(100/5,2) * 5` will give you the 10 unordered pairs.

You can then loop through the columns and enumerate, for each, the set of all permutations of asset allocations.  You'll have to deal carefully with the case where there are repeated elements - for example, we generate {100,0} which represents <100,0> and <0,100> whereas {50,50} only represents the single allocation <50,50>.  You can deal with this by using the `set` attribute of `permuatations`

`restrictedparts(100/5,20) * 5` gives 627 partitions that add up to 100% - and you'll need to permute each of these to get your full list of allocations.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer and explaining the output. I can generate the partition as you suggested. I don't really follow what you mean by "You can deal with this by using the set attribute of permuatations" and "you'll need to permute each of these to get your full list of allocations"... I'd be extremely grateful if you could please give an example with some code of how to turn this set into the restricted permutations. I appreciate your patience; I'm an engineer turned actuary, not a mathematician!

Comment: For example, with 3 assets, you get {80,10,10} as one of the columns of `restrictedparts(100/5,3) * 5`.  You then use `permutations(3,3,c(80,10,10), set=FALSE)` to generate all the permutations of these - we've used set=FALSE to stop the two 10's being merged.  You can wrap this in a `unique(...)` to get the three true permutations.

Answer (score 1):

In your problem, you will still have large number of combinations to deal with even after filtering.

Your problem essentially boils down to `n multichoose k` problem as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) 
You want to choose k=20 slots of 5% weightage each to allocate from n assets.

So in your example case of 20 assets, your number of combinations would still be

```
choose(39, 20)
## [1] 68923264410
```

I suggest you have a look at [`DEoptim`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEoptim/index.html) package which has specific examples directly related to your problem at hand. It uses differential evolution.

Comment: hummm, that's a very big number! AS you suggest I may have to adapt (no pun intended) my approach. We have access to a evolver model but it will take a bit of work. Sadly the portfolio model is currently in Excel (sorry, not much I can do about it!!) Thanks for your help!